# Speed up multiple yarn installs on Gitlab Runner

Tags: gitlab, hadoop-yarn, gitlab-ci-runner

I have multiple folders in a project that each have their own yarn.lock. When running on the Gitlab Runner, installing all the node modules through yarn is taking a long time even though I am using `yarn config set cache-folder`:

```
yarn config set cache-folder .yarn-cache

# For each folder with a yarn.lock file:
yarn install \
   --no-progress \
   --pure-lockfile \
   --ignore-platform
```

And then my `.gitlab.yml` file has the following:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - .yarn-cache
    - node_modules
```

I've tried caching each `node_modules` folder in each folder, but sometimes it stakes too long to download and upload the cache to s3 (over 20 minutes) and fails.

Is there a more appropriate why to do this? Or is there a way to speed up the multiple yarn installs?

---

It may be helpful to note that each of these use a local file node_module as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `yarn config set cache-folder .yarn-cache` sets the cache folder relative to which ever directory it is running from (at least in the version of yarn I was using).

I changed the line to yarn config set cache-folder "$(pwd)/.yarn-cache" so that it was an absolute path and it looks like the cache is working as expected now.

Comment: One-liner: `yarn install --pure-lockfile --cache-folder .yarn-cache`